# Does the postulate of special relativity say that speed of light in vacuum is the greatest speed?

Tags: special-relativity, speed-of-light, inertial-frames, speed

The postulate of relativity says that the speed of light in a vacuum is the **same** for all inertial observers. But does it also say that this speed is the **greatest** achievable speed?

Comment: The fact that it's the greatest speed, as far as I know, is a derived notion and not a postulate in itself. If you look at the Lorentz transformations for example you immediately see they make no sense for $v>c$, at least not without implying some exotic new physics (Tachyons, etc.) which would be a non-standard addition to the theory.

Comment: Possible duplicates: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/267852/2451 , https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/6406/2451 and links therein.